# Set product image using custom code in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, product, image, media

i want to set the product image from my folder.For that i am doing like this but no luck.

```
$image =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ."users/a.jpg";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$product->setSmallImage($image)
    ->setThumbnail($image)
    ->setImage($image)
    ->save();
```

Also try like this :

```
if(is_file($image))
{
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image, array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
}
```

What i miss ? thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same situation some days ago and this is what i did.

```
$fileName = $importData['image'];
    $filePath = $importDir . $fileName;
    $base = $importData["base_image"];
    $small = $importData["small_image"];
    $thumbnail = $importData["thumbnail"];

    $productId = $product->loadByAttribute('product_code', $importData['sku']);

    if ($productId) {

        $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array("thumbnail","small_image","image"), false, false);
    }

    try {
        $product->save();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'mylogfile.log');
    }
```

I used it to import multiple images at once using a csv file. Just replace the values $base,$small, $thumbnail with your images and you are good to go.

In your case that would be:

```
$image =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ."users".DS."a.jpg";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($image, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```